# datatables filter in different input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a problem with datatables. I can't enable bFilter in input outside table container. There is a code which I initialize my datatable.

```
var table = $('#table-perms-users').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": tableHeight + "px",
        "scrollX": "100%",
        "scrollXInner": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bSort" : true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "columns": [
            { "orderDataType": "dom-last-name"},
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" }
        ]
    } );
```

I try to enable filter with function fnFilter() on keyup event on input. It looks like that:

```
      $('#dTSearch').keyup(function(){
        table.fnFilter($(this).val());
      });
```

But I can see an error message on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):10086(anonymous function)
> (index):10086jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.1.11.1.js?t=1402046180:4641elemData.handle

Maybe someone can answer me what I doing wrong? Looks like it didn't see var table or didn't find function fnFilter. Maybe I have some mistakes in define my datatable?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Static mode of dataTables.

since you mentioned as "bFilter": false in the configuration of dataTable for you, probably does not allow you to filter.

if you make 
bFilter:true, it takes care of the filtering by default in static mode.

And check if fnFilter parameter value.
for more info on fnFilter you can open dataTables.js file (lib) you associated.

Comment: Yeah. I use static mode of dataTables. Enabling disabling bFilter option didnt change nothing. For fnFilter fucnciotn we can send 6 params but u think problem higher cos i cant find that function on page.

Answer (score 0):

All was more easy that i think. There end variant of code:

```
    $('#dTSearch').keyup(function()
    {
        table.columns(0).search($(this).val()).draw();
    });
```

UPD: bFilter option should be enabled.